# Scala Futures callback hell

Tags: scala, callback, future

I've been reading many times about Scala Futures reducing callback problems. I've got a code that started to look problematic.

```
val a = Future(Option(Future(Option(10))))

a.map { b =>
  b.map { c =>
    c.map { d =>
      d.map { res =>
        res + 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make this code more flat?

//Edit @againstmethod

```
for{
  b <- a
  c <- b
  d <- c
  res <- d
} yield res + 10
```

This code won't compile

> Error:(21, 8) type mismatch;  found   : Option[Int]  required:
>   scala.concurrent.Future[?]   res <- d
>         ^

Comment: if you came up with an example that actually compiles when one pastes it into an IDE, it might be easier to suggest improvements...

Comment: @KimStebel Just changed the code so it is more universal

Comment: You should avoid stacking `Future`'s in the first place, by using `Future.traverse` or `Future.sequence`.

Comment: No one would ever write real code that looks like this.  It's better to try something that could actually be real and then use that example to ask questions about the parts you don't understand.

Comment: This is a simplified version of code I have to deal with. And it's almost unmodified example of using reactivemongo, so yes people do write code like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer was pretty straight forward.

```
for { 
a <- b
c <- a.get
} yield c.get + 10
```

Appears to be enough, because when `x.get + 10` fails (because of `None + 10`) the future just fails. So it still works to use a simple fallback

```
val f = for { 
a <- b
c <- a.get
} yield c.get + 10
f fallbackTo Future.successful(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [for comprehension](http://nerd.kelseyinnis.com/blog/2013/11/12/idiomatic-scala-the-for-comprehension/). In example:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Stuff extends App {
  val result = for {
    f1 <- Future { 10 + 1 }
    f2 <- Future { f1 + 2 }
  } yield f2
  result.onComplete(println)
}
```

Where result will be 13.

Any class that implements a proper `map` and `flatMap` function can be used this way in a `for`.

If you don't mind another dependency, you can also use a library like scalaz and explicitly use monadic binding to flatten things out (EDIT encoded some Option types to address a comment below):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.{Success,Failure}

object BindEx extends App {

  def f1(i: String): Future[Int] = Future { i.length }
  def f2(i: Int): Future[Option[Double]] = Future { Some(i / Math.PI) }
  def f3(i: Option[Double]): Future[Option[Double]] = Future { 
    i match {
      case Some(v) => Some(Math.round(v))
      case _ => None
    } 
  }

  val result = 
    Monad[Future].point("Starting Point") >>= 
    f1 >>= 
    f2 >>=
    f3

  result.onComplete { x => 
    x match {
      case Success(value) => println("Success " + value)
      case Failure(ex) => println(ex)
    }  
  }

  Await.result(result, 1 seconds)
}
```

And finally, if you just have parallel operations that you want to bind after all have succeeded that are independent, you can use scalaz applicative builder:

```
  val result = (
    Future { 10 + 10 } |@| 
    Future { 20 - 3 } |@| 
    Future { Math.PI * 15 }
  ) { _ + _ / _}
  println(Await.result(result, 1 seconds))
```

This will let all 3 futures complete, then apply block to the 3 arguments.

Comment: Yes it's true. But for comprehension doesn't return anything on failure, right?

Comment: Correct and if you create them in line like that they will execute serially. It's just another tool that may help.

Comment: `result` is a `Future` in the way that makes sense; you can use `result.onFailure` or similar to handle failures. They don't just silently vanish.

Comment: But you do lose granularity.

Comment: But that doesnt allow me to extract value like  
`Future( Option ( Future ( Option ( 10 ) ) ) )`
Only `Future(Future(10))` or `Option(Option(10))`
And that's not the case here

Comment: I added an example of using a scalaz Monad to bind futures together to my answer. And yes, you're right, the Monad won't allow for different-typed monadic bindings in the same chain.

Comment: I encoded some options into my monad example, I don't think I know of any way to flatten across monadic types that vary.

Comment: Still these values are independent from each other. They're not nested, they're parallel

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used them yet, but they should be exactly what you're looking for: Monad transformers.

Basically, a monad transformer takes a Monad (such as Future) and adds functionality to it, such as the functionality provided by Option, and returns a transformed Monad. I think there is even an Option Monad transformer in Scalaz. That should allow you to use nested Options in Futures and still have a flat code structure using for comprehensions.

See http://blog.garillot.net/post/91731853561/a-question-about-the-option-monad-transformer and https://softwarecorner.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/scalaz-optiont-monad-transformer/ for some examples.